# How do I disable message sending using the return key on Ipad or Iphone? While using a bluetooth keyboard

Tags: messages

Using a Bluetooth keypad with my Ipad how do I compose a message with new paragraphs?    Pressing Énter/return’ sends the message immediately and message is most often incomplete. I also experience this with Facebook when posting messages!?

Comment: Try Shift/Return. I don't have a BT keyboard to test on an iPad, but that's what you use on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

By experience, latest macOS (11.1) and iPadOS (14.4) versions let you get a new line by pressing the Shift ⇧ + Enter ⏎

In older versions of iPadOS it would be pressing Option ⌥ + Enter ⏎ (same as for macOS)